# GRUB fails with 'symbol `grub_real_boot_time` not found'

Tags: boot, grub, arch-linux

I updated GRUB on Arch. When I try to boot, GRUB gives the error mentioned in the title. I know that grub_real_boot_time is provided by `boottime.mod`, but running `insmod boottime` fails with `error: symbol grub_boot_time_head not found`. I cannot boot from external media, as this machine has only a CD drive and all my linux discs are DVDs. What module provides the symbol `grub_boot_time_head`? I cannot try what is described on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173939 because I cannot boot from the install disc (or any external media).

EDIT: from looking at the GRUB source, I can see that `struct grub_boot_time *grub_boot_time_head` is defined in `misc.c`. However, there is no `misc.mod`. Also, I can find the string `grub_boot_time_head` in `boottime.mod` by running `grep`. What am I doing wrong? Is my hard disk corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, because I accidentally formatted my hard drive using gpt partition table, reformatting it in msdos solved the problem

Comment: I can't reformat

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the loader part (which de facto is a compiled program written into first sectors of the bootable disk) of the grub gets out of sync with it's loadable modules (located usually in the `/boot/grub2/i386-pc`) directory.

This, in turn, can happen for a number of reason but the most frequent one - you installed grub (while repairing your Linux installation) on a detached disk using OS version that is way older or way more recent than the OS that has been installed on a said disk. If this happened, you can sync the modules using **--root-directory=** switch of the `grub2-install` utility and specifying a mounted /boot of the disk that has been out of sync.